# COUNTIFS text value

Tags: excel, countif

I have the values of jobs completed in a date range by using

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N3:N5000, ">"&J2, Sheet2!N3:N5000, "<"&K2)

I define my date range by putting them in J2 and K2 respectively.

I now need to check the same date range but in a different range of cells, in this case I need to count the number of cells in Column "M" are "Successful" AND fall in the same date range. I have this:

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N3:N5000, ">"&J2, Sheet2!N3:N5000, "<"&K2,Sheet2!M2:M5000,"Successful")

That is only returning an error though, any help getting me sorted out would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranges must be aligned. Replace `M2:M5000` with `M3:M5000`

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N3:N5000, ">"&J2, Sheet2!N3:N5000, "
   <"&K2,Sheet2!M3:M5000,"Successful")
'               ^^
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it up! Good Catch!!